# @EnableRedisRepositories - What is the use of in Spring Data Redis?

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I search a lot over web to get more practical usage of ***@EnableRedisRepositories***, but I did not found any. Even in my `Spring Boot + Spring Data Redis` example, I removed `@EnableRedisRepositories` but still I did not understood what difference it make, still I can see data is persisting into DB and retrieving fine.

Can somebody please clarify ?

I went through this annotation, but not every clear..

> Annotation to activate Redis repositories. If no base package is configured through either {@link #value()},
>   {@link #basePackages()} or {@link #basePackageClasses()} it will trigger scanning of the package of annotated class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It lets Spring scan your packages for repository classes/interfaces and then use Redis as the storage to persist your objects to - instead of a classic relational database.

[Spring Data docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#why-spring-redis) tell us:

> NoSQL storage systems provide an alternative to classical RDBMS for horizontal scalability and speed. In terms of implementation, key-value stores represent one of the largest (and oldest) members in the NoSQL space.
>
> The Spring Data Redis (SDR) framework makes it easy to write Spring applications that use the Redis key-value store by eliminating the redundant tasks and boilerplate code required for interacting with the store through Spring’s excellent infrastructure support.

Comment: Even data is persisting into redis without this annotation and adding this annotation doesn't make any difference. Any other pointers?

Comment: Perhaps you are using Spring Boot with spring-boot-starter-data-redis?

Comment: Right. We're using this only. `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` fetches the `Spring Data Redis` version